# In perl,is there a module that automatically generates set/get accessor methods?

Tags: perl, oop

Anyone knows such a module?

Write it myself is just tedious..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Class::Accessor`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Class%3a%3aAccessor) is pretty standard, for non-Moose Perl.

Answer (score 8):

[Moose](http://www.iinteractive.com/moose/) will actually do this for you although it may not be in the most intuitive way.

Comment: Especially with MooseX::FollowPBP, which sets the Perl Best Practices naming scheme of set_ and get_ prefixes

Answer (score 2):

[MooseX::Declare](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MooseX%3a%3aDeclare) might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Moose`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose) as others have pointed out. For a lighter implementation, you could use [`Class::Accessor`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Class%3a%3aAccessor). Furthermore, it has an optional Moose-like interface as well.

[`Class::Accessor`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Class%3a%3aAccessor) has a `follow_best_practice` method which will enforce setters and getters to follow Damian Conway's advice in *Perl Best Practices* about their naming.

Answer (score 2):

Mouse (Esp Mouse::XS) seems to get the best [performance](http://blogs.perl.org/users/michael_g_schwern/2011/03/and-the-fastest-oo-accessor-is.html) these days (YMMV). It's like a lightweight moose.

Answer (score 1):

**Use Moose to automatically generate set/get accessor methods**

https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose

Answer (score 1):

[Class::XSAccessor](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Class%3a%3aXSAccessor) will generate very fast accessors and has some flexibility, but I would recommend skipping directly to [Mouse](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Mouse) which is a faster, slimmer, compatible [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose) which is a complete OO system.